# ServerRuntimeConfig is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am working on my nextjs project under docker, and when using `getStaticProps` my backend api is not available(which is also under docker).  So I connected frontend to backend via `networks` and if i hardcode `api` for ssr request it works. But when i try to utilize `serverRuntimeConfig` and `publicRuntimeConfig` so i could switch between them depending on where code is being ran I get `{}` for serverRuntimeConfig. However `publicRuntimeConfig` is fine and i can access api from it.
My `next.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        // Will be available on both server and client
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost/api/v1',
    },
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
        // Will only be available on the server side
        baseUrl: 'http://backend_nginx_1/api/v1/',
    },
```

am I missing something ?

Comment: It's recommended to use build-time [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) to provide such configuration.

Comment: @juliomalves, I saw this recommendation in the docs, but then if you would like to connect frontend to DEV, STAGE and PROD, you would need to build 3 images.=, which sounds a bit suboptimal. Or do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sound dumb, but I spent 2 hours seeing the empty file been recognized by the system and just seeing {}.
Now... restarting the server, gives you access to the content of the file.
That was my solution.

And it was not included in the documentation.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration